# How to invalidate previous session in oidc-client-js if user login's again in different browser?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, oidc-client-js

I am using aws congnito and oidc-client-js for user authentication. If user logins again in different browser how to invalidate sessions if he is previously logged in ?

Comment: If the single-signon enabled, why would the user get to login page?

Comment: Okay my bad , let me rephrase what if users tries to login in different browser ? can we get a details of previously logged in sessions ? @hashbytes